# WinDbg, SOS, how to dump all strings on stack

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, sos

How can I print the string value of all the System.String objects on the current thread's clrstack?

Pseudo code for what I want to do:

```
foreach ($string in !dso -type System.String) !do $string
```

or better yet

```
foreach ($string in !dso -type System.String) !printstring $string
```

even better yet

```
foreach (distinct $string in !dso -type System.String) !printstring $string
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest SOSEX extension (v4) has the `!mdso` command which has the type filtering option `/t`.

```
SOSEX - Copyright 2007-2012 by Steve Johnson - http://www.stevestechspot.com/
To report bugs or offer feedback about SOSEX, please email sjjohnson@pobox.com

mdso
Usage: !sosex.mdso [Options]

Dumps object references on the stack and in CPU registers in the current context

Options:

/t:typeFilter - Limits the output to objects whose type name matches the filter expression specified by "typeFilter".
                 Cannot be combined with the /mt option.
```

so a command of `!mdso /t:System.String` should work.

Comment: Thanks, that works well as mdso already prints the string content

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to look for string objects references among addresses of the stack. For example, we know stack bottom address(0x000000001821CEF0), and stack top address (000000001821E3F0). We can loop through all addresses in this range (w/ 8 bytes step) and output object details.

```
.for (r $t0=0x000000001821CEF0;@$t0<000000001821E3F0;r $t0=@$t0+0x8){ !do poi(@$t0) }
```

Comment: There's no `-type` (nor `-short`) flag for the `!dso` command.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really work. As Brian says, there is no type flag (nor a -short flag, I think)

Comment: Thanks. If I could do .foreach ( ico {!dso -short}) {!do ico } I could then grep for all the strings, but without the -short flag, this is not working well at all...

Comment: Thanks, the second suggestion works pretty well, if output to a text file followed by greping for "String:"

Comment: @BenSchwehn I hope there is a way to filter objects by type using .if statement. Unfortunately, I am facing issues in case of wrong addresses on the stack. I'll update the answer once find proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use !sosex.strings.  This command will allow you to view the values of all strings, or to filter them by size, content or GC generation.

Comment: Thanks. However, this loses the relation to the particular stack I'm interested in. I sometimes find it useful to look at the top N strings in a callstack, so I would like to have a command that simply dumps those only.

Comment: I apologize.  I misread your question as heap, rather than stack.

Comment: Looks like your sosex is still a very good solution using !mdso /t:System.String as suggested by jcopenha